# VM migration of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql

We have two SQL Server VMs (SQL 2005 x64 on Windows 2003x64) both have RDM SAN. The SQL Servers are also clustered. My VM admin will be migrating us to different VMs using Cisco UCS solution. Unfortunately we will not be doing failover cluster to the new VMs.

Will it be possible to disable the cluster service and start SQL Server or would you need to uninstall SQL Server from Clustering and reinstall?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this but I think you would need to re-install SQL Server. You can have one node in a cluster though, if that helps.